# Hiding border behind transparent tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am experimenting with a tab script that will display different information depending on which tab you hover over.  I am trying to do this with a transparent background color on the tabs and the main content window. The right border for the tabs is hidden which is fine, but the border for the main content can be seen through the transparent background.  I want the graphic to flow from the tab over to the content but I cannot figure out how to hide the border JUST in the places to the right of the ACTIVE tab.  I have created a JSFiddle page to give a visual.

[Tab Example - via JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tA8AS/)

HTML:

```
<div id="vtab">
                <ul>
                    <li class="home selected"></li>
                    <li class="login"></li>
                    <li class="support"></li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                   <h1>Profile 1</h1>
                   <p>This is where profile 1 will go</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Profile 2</h1>
                   <p>This is where profile 2 will go</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                   <h1>Profile 3</h1>
                   <p>This is where profile 3 will go</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
        background: black;
        font-family: verdana;
        padding-top: 50px;
        color: white;
    }
    #vtab {
        margin: auto;
        width: 900px;
        height: 100%;

    }
    #vtab > ul > li {
        width: 440px;
        height: 90px;
        background-color: rgba(23,23,23,.5) !important;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
        border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        position: relative;
        border-right: none;
        opacity: .3;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30);             
    }

    #vtab > ul > li.selected {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
        border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
        border-right: none;
        z-index: 10;
        background-color: rgba(23,23,23,.5) !important;
        position: relative;
    }
    #vtab > ul {
        float: left;
        width: 440px;
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
        margin: auto 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 80px;
    }
    #vtab > div {
        background-color: rgba(23,23,23,.5);
        margin-left: 440px;
        border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
        min-height: 500px;
        padding: 12px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9;
        -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
        var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
        $items.mouseover(function() {
            $items.removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            var index = $items.index($(this));
            $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
        }).eq(1).mouseover();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get that to work drawing the border in a pseudo element around the selected li

CSS

```
.selected:before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     right: 0px;
     bottom: 100%; 
     width: 0px;
     border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
     height: 1000px;
     display: block;
}
.selected:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     right: 0px;
     top: 100%; 
     width: 0px;
     border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
     height: 1000px;
     display: block;
}
```

This draws the pseudo elements. What is left is to clip them (because we don't know the dimensions needed:

```
    #vtab {
        margin: auto;
        width: 900px;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

And stop drawing the border in the main div:

```
#vtab > div {
    background-color: rgba(23,23,23,.5);
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9a9a9;
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0px;
}
```

### [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tA8AS/5/)

[no backgrounds fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tA8AS/7/show)

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better but there is still a visible border line. Perhaps my best option is to not use the border at all for the look I am trying to achieve. Thank you for the input, it is appreciated!

Comment: You see a border line ? What browser are you using ?

Comment: Chrome. I checked it on Firefox and IE9 and can see it as well. Its faded/faint, but its there under the transparent background.

Comment: Yes, now I see it. It's not a border, but the place where 2 backgrounds met. I have done another fiddle, whitout backgrounds, and now it isn't there

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove/hide a part of the border. What you can do is make your tabs overlap the border but since your tabs are transparent you'll still see the content's border.

You can however set your selected tab to be the same color as your background.

```
body, #vtab > ul > li.selected {
    background: black !important;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tA8AS/4/)

Comment: Because the tabs are transparent the border behind them is still visible.

Comment: I have an image background over the actual version, so I cannot match the color.  However I am also currently using NO borders which looks alright, I was just wondering if there was a way to fix it.  I really wanted to use the border but I want the color to flow from the tab into the content, without the visible border.  thanks for the help!

Comment: In that case I don't think there is a way to do it. Maybe by using Javascript but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I used the method described here:

http://foolproof.me/post/21647970230/transparent-tabs

The idea is to create all the borders directly on the tab, even the bottom one. The bottom one has a width of 999em and overflow is used on parent elements to control the visible part.

From the article in that page:

Let's say you have the following HTML

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a class="tab" href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="active tab" href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab" href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab" href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Create the tab look:

```
.tabs {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.tab {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

CSS for the active tab and the borders:

```
.tab.active {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Bottom border with a gap:

```
.tab.active::after,
.tab.active::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 999em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  pointer-events: none;
}
.tab.active::before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.tab.active::after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```